# Can not read property of undefined i18n

Tags: javascript, properties, internationalization

When I try to pass language dynamically from select dropdown list, It shows following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined at changeLanguage
```

where `changeLanguage` is my function as follows:

```
function changeLanguage(lang) 
{ 
 lang = lang || "en_EN"; // if no language is set, use the browser's default 
 jQuery.i18n.properties({ 
 path : 'language', 
 mode : 'both', language: lang,
 name: 'Messages', 
 callback: refresh_i18n }); 
}
```

The following are the pictures of it:

[image: Dropdown image]

[image: Console error]

What is wrong with the code?
Please do suggest!
Thanks

**UPDATE**:
FOR MORE EXPLANATION:
This is my index file and initially I call it with onload it works fine.

```
<script> 
function refresh_i18n() { 
  console.log('Some code...') 
} 
function changeLanguage(lang) { 
     lang = lang || "en_EN"; 
     jQuery.i18n.properties({ 
     path : 'js/libs/language', 
     mode : 'both', 
     language: lang, 
     callback: refresh_i18n 
   });
} 
changeLanguage("en_US"); 
</script>
```

but when i call by changing dropdown like:

```
$('#selectLanguage').change(function(){ 
    changeLanguage(this.value); 
});
```

It gives above error

Comment: Have you added i18n reference and initialized it?

Comment: Did you properly include the library? https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n

Comment: update your question. Do not add code in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probrably the i18n library is loading before the jquery (problems haha).

So, put the jQuery loading in the head of the html and the plugin i18n (and others, if you are using) in the body (I suggest in the end of body) of the html.

That must solve the problem.

Comment: So we need more code to see what is happening. Could you do that? (a fiddle could be better).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Resolved as i18n library file loaded after the body tag.